# detecting user idle (no user input) time globally on Linux or better cross platform

Tags: python

Is there a way to detect no user input (mouse or keyboard) using Python in Linux. I've found some recipes for Windows and Mac but not something consistent. I am assuming there is no cross platform alternative or library unless I missed it.

Comment: Windows and Linux are *different* operating systems.  It's hard to be "consistent".  Can you be more specific on what you think *consistency* might mean?

Answer (score 3):

There is no cross-platform solution, but I made a very simple python 2 module for X11 that specifically addresses your concern: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/actmon

`actmon.get_idle_time()` returns the age of last user activity in milliseconds.

Comment: It doesn't work for python2 or 3: https://pastebin.com/0JrZEjie

Comment: @SurpriseDog You lack X11 dev header files. You're on a debian? I think that `apt-file find scrnsaver.h` should help you find what you lack.